# How do I print the name of a function I've passed via an argument in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Writing a test function for two different functions isMemberR and isMemberI
it passes these functions as an argument f to the testing function bintest.
The testing works fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the output in the correct format and say the name of the function being tested.

```
def bintest(f):
    '''
    (function) -> None
    Tests a search function for given parameter.
    '''
    fname = str(f)
    testTruthValues = [True, False, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, False]
    testSequences = [(1, 2, 3, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 3, 4), 'aeiou', 'aeiou', (1, 3, 5, 7), (23, 24, 25, 26, 27), (0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3), (2, 10), (99, 100), (42,), (43,), ()]
    testTargets = [3, 99, 'i', 'y', 4, 5, 4, 3, 1, 10, 101, 42, 44, 99]
    for i in range (0, len(testSequences)):
        truthvalue = f(testSequences[i], testTargets[i])
        if truthvalue == testTruthValues[i]:
            print('Checking:', fname, testSequences[i], '... its value', truthvalue, 'is correct!')
        else:
            print('Checking:', fname, testSequences[i], '... its value', truthvalue, 'is incorrect!')
```

my output looks like this:
Checking:  (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ... its value True is correct!
The output the lesson wants looks like this:
Checking isMemberR((99, 100), 101)...its value False is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fname = f.__qualname__` instead of `fname = str(f)`